# Why map viewer in Oracle spatial database SQL developer shows mirrored and rotated view?How to solve it?

Tags: google-maps, oracle-sqldeveloper, oracle-spatial, oracle-map-viewer

I took the longitudes and latitudes of the red marked areas in the image given below from google map and inserted them in Oracle Spatial database.

[image]

But when I graphically show it by selecting "Invoke Map View on result set" from the option like image given below in SQL developer.

[image]

But it the image has two problems:

1. It shows **mirrored** image.
2. It shows **90 degree rotated** image.

See the image given below to be clear:

[image]

My questions are:

- Why it rotates and mirrors?
- How to show it as it is in google map?

Comment: Wild guess: you have the longitude and latitude backwards somewhere.

Comment: @geocodezip could you please elaborate? I could not get you. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In google map geodetic data format is (Latitude, Longitude), on the other hand in Oracle spatial database system the format is (Longitude, Latitude), that's why you got rotated and mirrored image. If you set the format as (Longitude, Latitude) hope then you will get the actual image.

Comment: You are absolutely right. How tactful thing you have caught. This is over looked by us even our course teacher! I took time and changed all my data. Now, it is giving correct result. Thanks a lot.